# JPA Criteria returning a single row from a join

Tags: java, jpa, join, criteria

Given the database relationship:

```
sport-club table
================
id
...


player
======
id
sport-club-id (reference sport-club)
first-name
...
```

I wish to find all sport clubs with someone names "John".

I wrote the following JPA:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SportClub> query = cb.createQuery(SportClub.class);
Root<SportClub> sportClub = query.from(SportClub.class);
Join<Player> player = sportClub.join(Player_.sportClub);
query.where(cb.equal(player.get(Player_.firstName), "John"));
```

However due to the join this returns the sport club once for each player called John in each club. How can I get Criteria to return the club once for each player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was much simpler than I thought. I simply had to add:

```
query.distinct(true);
```

I spent a few hours fruitlessly trying to make the join work as I wanted.